# Is there any progress bar/timer for Android?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

As you can see on the 
[image: attachment]
, I need a progress bar for my android app. Is there anything similar to the attached one above?

Comment: Refer this library https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: http://www.tiemenschut.com/how-to-customize-android-progress-bars/

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Trinea/android-open-project/tree/master/English%20Version#7-progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no implementation for it directly in the android sdk, but there are some projects that help you to achieve that, one of them is [ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) and another one is [CircleDisplay](https://github.com/PhilJay/CircleDisplay).

And i think **Circle Display** will help you better, as stated in their GitHub page you can control it completely like:

```
CircleDisplay cd = (CircleDisplay) findViewById(R.id.circleDisplay);
cd.setAnimDuration(3000);
cd.setValueWidthPercent(55f);
cd.setTextSize(36f);
cd.setColor(Color.GREEN);
cd.setDrawText(true);
cd.setDrawInnerCircle(true);
cd.setFormatDigits(1);
cd.setTouchEnabled(true);
cd.setSelectionListener(this);
cd.setUnit("%");
cd.setStepSize(0.5f);
// cd.setCustomText(...); // sets a custom array of text
cd.showValue(75f, 100f, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) here is a good collection of donut progress bars. Also I recommend you to browse [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/76) site this is a good collection of free custom controls for android.